# How do you create this specific stained glass effect on a font?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

[image]I really like this stained glass effect on this font and want to recreate it. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest/fastest way is to simply apply an image to a text using masks:

[image]

- Start by inserting an image you want to use as background for the text;
- Add the text with the `Text Tool`;
- Apply the image to the text as a mask (place the image layer on top of the text layer, and use Alt + Click in the space between the layers).

<sub>[Image source](http://www.loyalgallery.com/gl014_dearraindrop.html)</sub>

Comment: where did you find this image?